# Discussing questions outside the forum and use votes

Tags: discussion

We are a team working together and all of us are active in SO. Sometimes we tend to discuss SO questions/answers among ourselves and might use up/down votes for the questions/answers of the team members based on our private discussions here. So, it's a closed team using up/down votes for each others activity.

Is this against the rules of SO?

Comment: Are you voting on each other's posts, or does your team only conflate votes on posts from other users?

Comment: We do both. (And also please note that this question is about a hypothetical situation)

Comment: Well, voting on each other's posts in a big no-no, and can result in your accounts being merged or deleted. Having a team mass-vote other posts is more of a gray area (some people meet up in chat to do just that I believe, so there is a precedent).

Comment: ".. based on our private discussions .." so you do **not** bias your votes on them being co-workers (either positively or negatively). Sounds alright to me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: there is actually a precedent right here: [the Meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/2564301).

Comment: @Jongware, true, but that's more chaotic than organized. I'm not sure a team actively meeting up to decide votes falls in the same category.

Comment: Its a personal thing. Me personally I try to not vote at all if I'm influenced in some way - usually emotions (which is difficult). Its not a problem to make that choice, SO does not suffer from a single vote not happening on a question or answer. If you follow the same strategy for the questions you discuss in private then there is no risk of clashing with the organized voting detection routines. If anything you might park the question/answer and vote on it a couple of days later when the mind has had the chance to take full ownership of it.